# Is there a way to get a non encoded file name from a Path object in JNI on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, character-encoding, java-native-interface, filenames

I have a Java application running on Linux that passes file names and paths to a JNI method.

This application gets a String from the Path object and passes that to the JNI method.

Here is the problem, the Path object internally stores an original byte array that represents the file name.  The Path object returns a String object that can not always be reversed back to the original byte array.  This most likely occurs because nothing says a Linux file name has to be UTF-8 encoded.

When I try and use the path string in JNI to fopen a file things fail horribly for certain file names that have odd characters in them.

Is there some way or method to find the original byte array that represents the file name?